# Is there any map maker for javaME game?

Tags: java, mobile, slick

For the past two weeks I was trying to make a map maker for my java ME 2D RPG game. I failed because i get errors using slick TWL and the forum for this is inactive.

So I just wondered is there anyone that knows slick TWL (Themable Widget Library)? Or maybe do you know a good MapMaker where i could upload my map elements build a map and get numbers to use them for building map with LayerManager class?

Already found one http://sourceforge.net/projects/tilemapeditor2d/. But the thing is my map elements are in different .png images. In one of those images there is 16 elements (trees water and etc) and those kind of images are 29. So it would be hard to build a map with LayerManager

Well I was thinking putting everything into one image and that way it would be simplier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know of any tile map editors utilizing numbers for the tiles. However, you can parse a XML file into your map.

A popular 2D Tile map editor "Tiled" can be found [here](http://www.mapeditor.org/). This should also fix your multiple images problem. I'm not quite sure how "LayerManager" works in Slick, but if it renders the tiles based off numbers, you can use the solution above & convert the XML you read into numbers.

Also, I've never been a huge fan of everything inside one image (Not sprite sheets, I mean the entire map). It's normally a better idea that the game elements handle drawing themselves. When you put put everything in one image, it also forces you to manually import the various game objects coordinates, heights/widths, etc, for collision detection & whatever else you need. This is really bad practice & just makes it harder for you.

What is fine, is too have a non-interactive background image just there for detail / scenery (Normally you would see this in a side scroller, behind the tiles. A sky background could also be an example of this).

Comment: But I can not seem to find a code to copy in Tiled (int array with numbers to use later)

Comment: Tiled produces an XML File. This contains everything about the actual map. When the game / level first loads, you can read this XML file, and transform the tile value into an int.